Odoo access rule domain based on another field on the model
Is it possible to define the domain force of a record rule based on a computed field on the same model? For example
<field name="domain_force">[('employee_id','in',employee_ids.ids)]</field>

Here, employee_id and employee_ids (computed) are fields on the model.
Odoo gives me an error
Invalid domain: <class 'NameError'>: "name 'employee_ids' is not defined"

Other variations I tried are object.employee_ids, obj.employee_ids, self.employee_ids but none works. How can I achieve this?

In Odoo, defining a record rule based on a computed field directly in the domain_force attribute can be challenging because the domain expression used in XML is evaluated in a specific context that doesn't have direct access to Python variables or computed fields. However, you can achieve similar functionality by using a workaround that involves ensuring the computed field is stored and then using it in the domain.
Here’s how you can set this up: Step-by-Step Guide
Make the Computed Field Storable
First, ensure that your computed field (employee_ids) is stored in the database. This is necessary because domains in record rules can only use stored fields.
    from odoo import models, fields, api
    
    class YourModel(models.Model):
        _name = 'your.model'
    
        employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee")
        employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', compute='_compute_employee_ids', store=True)
    
        @api.depends('employee_id')
        def _compute_employee_ids(self):
            for record in self:
                # Your logic to compute employee_ids
                # Example: If you want to add all employees under a department
                record.employee_ids = some_logic_to_compute_ids(record.employee_id)

Ensure that store=True is set for the computed field to make it storable.
Define the Record Rule
With the computed field stored, you can now reference it in your record rule using a direct domain expression.
    <record id="your_model_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Your Model Access Rule</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('employee_id', 'in', [emp.id for emp in user.employee_ids])]</field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('your_module.group_name'))]"/>
    </record>

Important Notes
Storing Computed Fields: For domains, only stored fields can be used. Ensure that your logic for the computed field is efficient since it will be triggered on each record create/update that affects the dependency fields.
Using User Context: You can't directly use computed fields in the domain expression, so consider using the user variable, which is often available in the domain context. Here, I've shown an example of checking against user.employee_ids. You might need to adjust this depending on how you are managing employee access in your app.
Security and Performance: Be cautious when setting up domains in record rules, especially if the logic involves Many2many fields, as it could impact performance if not carefully designed.
Testing and Validation: Always test your domain thoroughly in a development environment to ensure it behaves as expected before deploying it to production. Make sure the employee_ids field is correctly updated for all records.
Conclusion
By making the computed field storable, you can use it in record rules. If your logic is more complex or involves dynamic data that can't be pre-computed and stored, consider implementing the logic in Python using method overrides or custom access control checks. This approach gives you more flexibility but might require custom development beyond simple XML domain expressions.

I was able to achieve what I needed some other way. That aside, I do understand the bit about fields in domains required to be stored (in my case I was using a computed field with a search function which normally should make computed fields searchable). I'm however unclear on user.employee_ids because this field is on the model on which I'm adding the rule not the user model. Generally, the two models could be completely unrelated

Oh great. I thought "employee_ids" is related with user model. So which solution way did you found ?
